# How to get the text color of textfield in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to get the text color of text field to check the condition and perform some functionality.But I am not able to get any proper method for it?Kindly Help me out.

Comment: Maybe it would help those willing to answer, when you show your "best attempt" or the closest API function you did find (that does not work)?

Answer (score 2):

```
UIColor* color = [textField textColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIColor *color = textField.textColor;
```

Comment: Please don't provide spoon feeding at-least ask user  what he tried.